# Getting Installed Steam Games From Registry

Tags: vb.net, steam

Can someone help me with this error I'm getting? Error14 'Using' operand of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' must implement 'System.IDisposable'

```
 Public Function GetInstalledGames() As Object
    Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of String) = Nothing
    Dim list As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(String.Concat(Me.SteamPath, "\steamapps")).ToList()
    Using strs As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        enumerator = list.Distinct().GetEnumerator()
        While enumerator.MoveNext()
            Dim current As String = enumerator.Current
            If (current.Contains("appmanifest_") And current.Contains(".acf")) Then
                strs.Add(Path.GetFileName(current).Replace("appmanifest_", "").Replace(".acf", ""))
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    Return strs
End Function


 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of String) = Nothing
        Me.tbOutput.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        Me.SteamPath = Conversions.ToString(Me.GetSteamPath())
        Using installedGames As List(Of String) = DirectCast(Me.GetInstalledGames(), List(Of String))
            enumerator = installedGames.Distinct().GetEnumerator()
            While enumerator.MoveNext()
                Dim current As String = enumerator.Current
                Me.lbGames.Items.Add(current)
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
```

[image: Error Here]

Comment: `GetInstalledGames` is defined as returning `Object`

Comment: How did you manage to make returning and iterating through a simple list of strings so complicated?

Comment: Just declare the variable as usual without `Using`. `Using` is for disposable things. Also, why are you using explicit enumerators instead of `For Each` loops? And why does `GetInstalledGames` return an `Object` instead of a list or `IEnumerable(Of String)` (since that‘s what it really is and what you cast it to)?

Comment: Ya but it's not adding the Steam app's to the listbox, But It's adding their exe to desktop tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Stop writing explicit enumerator loops for no reason
- Make your functions return types that make sense instead of `Object`
- Don’t sprinkle `Using` into code without knowing what it does
- Pass data between functions through arguments, not class fields

```
Private Shared Function GetInstalledGames(steamPath As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    For Each name In Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(steamPath, "steamapps"))
        If name.Contains("appmanifest_") AndAlso name.Contains(".acf") Then
            result.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name).Replace("appmanifest_", ""))
        End If
    Next

    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.tbOutput.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

    Dim steamPath As String = Me.GetSteamPath()

    For Each current In GetInstalledGames(steamPath).Distinct()
        Me.lbGames.Items.Add(current)
    Next
End Sub
```